# Migrate Spring from Jboss to Wildfly will cause "can not autowired"

Tags: spring-mvc

After upgrade Jboss to Wildfly, some of the services can not "Autowired". Will got NullpointerException.
Is anyone have experience or suggestions on this?

Comment: Did you define component scan correctly? please add more information

Comment: Yes, is in applicationContext.xml. This program can run in Jetty and everything is work. But can not deploy to wildfly.

Comment: Add your application.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the point. "Can not autowired" is not caused by the Spring upgrade.
It's because of Jboss 7 migrate to Wildfly.

You should create a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` in `WEB-INF` folder as follows:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="jaxrs" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
      ...
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

No matter what, I still want to say thanks to all of you.